# Combine assign publisher to PassthroughSubject

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, combine

I have following RxSwift view model code:

```
private(set) var num = BehaviorRelay<Int>(value: 1)
private let indexTrigger = PublishRelay<Int>()
private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

private func setupBindings() {
   //...
   self.num.distinctUntilChanged().bind(to: self.indexTrigger).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
}

func numSelected(num: Int) {
   self.num.accept(num)
}
```

This code is working fine and does what I want. I'm trying to do same, but with swift Combine framework with following code:

```
@Published private(set) var num: Int = 1
private let indexTrigger = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()
private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

private func setupBindings() {
   //...
   self.$num.removeDuplicates().sink(receiveValue: { [weak self] num in
      self.indexTrigger.send(num)
   }).store(in: &self.subscriptions)
}

func numSelected(num: Int) {
   self.num = num
}
```

So RxSwift binding looks much clean and simple and without need of weak. I tried to check `assign(on:)` method in combine, but seems it is not the one. Is there way to do same thing?

Comment: I don't see anything that isn't "clean and simple" about your Combine code, except for the overall architecture. What's the purpose of using a `sink` subscribed to one publisher to do a `send` to another publisher? By Occam's Razor, shouldn't we just remove one of those publishers entirely? If not, can you explain what large goal requires this strange use of two publishers "chained" in this artificial manner? (You can certainly chain publishers, but the way to do that is with `flatMap`, and in this situation I don't understand why you need to chain two publishers at all.)

Comment: `num` - it is param, which user can change from UI and it has to be displayed, so that's why I need this property to be published. At same time when this property changed I need to trigger request, that is why `indexTrigger` used.

Comment: Well, as I said, the way to "trigger request" in response to the change is to use `flatMap`. I would use a Deferred Future in the `flatMap` if the "request" involves networking. — I would also like to add that if that's the question, you might want to _make_ it the question. Don't show some artificial reduction; show what you are really trying to do. It makes it a lot easier to give meaningful help.

Comment: You're right, I should use `flatMap` directly on `num` publisher.

Comment: Hang on a moment, I'm about to give it as an answer. :) just working out a toy example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to "chain" publishers. The way to chain publishers is not to have two separate publishers with the second one poked by a `.sink` and a `.send`; it is to use `.flatMap` in the pipeline.

In your comment, you said that what you *really* want to do in the second publisher is "trigger request". That sounds like networking. So in your `.flatMap` you would provide a publisher that does the networking.

Here is a *toy* example, just to show you the form:

```
import UIKit
import Combine

func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @Published var num: Int = 1
    var storage = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    func setupPipeline() {
        $num.removeDuplicates()
            .flatMap { self.makeNetworkingFuture($0) }
            .sink { print($0) }
            .store(in: &self.storage)
    }
    
    func makeNetworkingFuture(_ i: Int) -> AnyPublisher<Int,Never> {
        URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: URL(string:"https://www.example.com")!)
            .map{_ in i}
            .replaceError(with: -1000)
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupPipeline()
        delay(1) { self.num = 1 }
        delay(2) { self.num = 1 }
        delay(3) { self.num = 2 }
        delay(4) { self.num = 2 }
        delay(5) { self.num = 3 }
    }
}
```

That's a very silly example, in the sense that although we do some networking, we don't show the *result* of that networking. I'm just outputting an Int (the same Int that came down the pipeline from `num`). But when you run the example, what you will see in the output is `1`, then `2`, then `3`, proving that we are removing duplicates, and networking *is* actually taking place on each of those occasions, as you can demonstrate to yourself in other ways.

Comment: I remembered from where my initial concept came. As I said: `num` - it is param, which user can change from UI and it has to be displayed, so that's why I need this property to be published. At same time when this property changed I need to trigger request, that is why `indexTrigger` used. Also user can to do pull to refresh (this part I missed). As you can see I'm doing removing of duplicates for `num`, hence I can't do refresh with same `num`, that is why I brought `indexTrigger` and use `reload` method with sending value to trigger.

Comment: As far as I can understand this is only useful if your creating a new publisher each time. What if you just want to pass the stream of values into a PassthroughSubject that exists already on some object you can't touch?

Comment: @Jonathan. I disagree with your premise. Anyway if you have a new question please pose it as a question!

Comment: I sort of feel the same as @Jonathan, so I've made another question! Would love to know why you disagree @matt! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72010969/combine-bind-publisher-to-passthroughsubject

Comment: Not the correct answer, please see Michael Henry's answer below for a more accurate alternative in Combine.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I did to bind to `PassthroughSubject<Output, Failure>`, making it kind of similar to `RxSwift` (and to reduce the number of the `sink` closure which is not needed for binding purposes).

You can simply, use the `subscribe(subject: S)` in replacement for `bind(to:)`:

Please refer to this documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/subscribe(_:)-3fk20

```swift
private func setupBindings() {
    //...
    self.$num.subscribe(indexTrigger).store(in: &subscriptions)
}
```

And that's it.

Cheers,
Kel

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer, and what the original question was referring to.