# Combine bind Publisher to PassthroughSubject

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, combine

This question has effectively been asked before ([Combine assign publisher to PassthroughSubject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64957228/combine-assign-publisher-to-passthroughsubject)) but the answer assumed the architecture of the question's example was totally wrong.

I'm faced with the same issue, in what I feel is a different example case, and I'd dearly love clarity on the issue.

---

I have a viewmodel class which provides a public `errorMessage` publisher for the client layer to do what it will with. Just a string here. Privately this publisher is backed by a `PassthroughSubject` - I'm "entering the monad" from different places internally and so I want to send error messages imperatively at that stage.

One of my entry points here happens to be another Combine publisher. I'd like to just map and bind, as I would in RxSwift:

```
private let _errorMessageSubject = PublishSubject<String>()
public let errorMessageRail = _errorMessageSubject.asObservable()

private func setup() {
   ...

   myEngine.errorMessages
     .map { msg in "Internal error: \(msg)" } 
     .bind(to: _errorMessageSubject)
   
   ...
}

private func someOtherMethod() {
   _errorMessageSubject.onNext("Surprise")
}
```

In Combine I'm not sure how to do it other than:

```
private let _errorMessageSubject = PassthroughSubject<String,Never>()
public let errorMessageRail = _errorMessageSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()

private func setup() {
   ...

   myEngine.errorMessages
     .map { msg in "Internal error: \(msg)" } 
     .sink { [weak self] msg in
         self?._errorMessageSubject.send(msg)
     }
   
   ...
}

private func someOtherMethod() {
   _errorMessageSubject.send("Surprise")
}
```

---

Before we get into chatting concurrency issues, let's say I'm always carefully pushing to `_errorMessageSubject` on a specific dispatch queue. I omit that from the code above for clarity.

So given this example, unless I'm missing something staggeringly obvious a flatMap won't help me here.

- Am I stuck with this sink -> send dance?
- Or is there some eye-watering code-smell about my public/private publisher/subject pattern (that I use a lot for bridging imperative with reactive architectures) and can some kind soul point me in the direction of self-improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want your rail to be the merge of `_errorMessageSubject` and another publisher.  So I'll make `errorMessageRail` a variable so it can be changed (by this class only) after it's initialized:

```
public private(set) var errorMessageRail = _errorMessageSubject.eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

Then, in setup, you change the rail so it includes the additional stream:

```
   func setup() {
        ...

        errorMessageRail = _errorMessageSubject.merge( with:
            myEngine.errorMessages
                .map { msg in "Internal error: \(msg)" }
        ).eraseToAnyPublisher()

    }
```

Comment: Ah great, thanks for this alternative approach!